# Displaying count of missing fields

Tags: kibana

I have an index of data; for example Animals and all data under Animals has 10 fields but some has 9 fields; for example field:human.

In a pie graph, I want to show the count of all data with column human and count of data without the column human.

How can I do it within a pie graph?

Answer (score 0):

In `Split Slices` Bucket, use the `Terms Aggregation` on `human` field and don't forget to tick `Show missing values` checkbox. You will get the required result in the pie chart. Check out the following screen for reference.

[image]